# Create Field with specific permissions in django

Tags: python, django

I want to add a field in my module to give the user some
permissions like `is_superuser` field. But how can i do this with customize permission?

```
    class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
        username = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
        email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
        image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics ')
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'),default=timezone.now)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

        objects = CustomUserManager()
```

Comment: Usually permissions are stored in *groups*. A user can belong to zero, one or more groups. A user has a permission if it belongs to a group with that permission.

Answer (score 1):

You can use groups:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
...
new_group, _ = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='new_group')
...
user.groups.add(new_group)
...
if user.groups.filter(name=new_group).exists():
    # good to go
```